# Memgraph Broker Transport Failure registering Kafka Stream Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb, memgraph

I started Memgraph with the Confluent Kafka Platform according to the [docker-compose.yml file](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka). After that, I created a Kafka Topic called *myTopic*, to which the data is streamed. Now I want to implement a consumer called *my_stream* with a transformation module according to the [documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/graph-stream-processing-with-kafka). The stream settings look like this
[image: Stream Settings]

When I add my transformation module, attach it to the stream and try to connect the stream, the following Error is thrown:

```
Transformation Failed
Failed to initialize Kafka consumer my_stream : Local: Broker transport failure
```

A more detailed description of the error from the terminal where the docker-compose.yml file is running:

[image: MemgraphError]

Looking at the Confluent Cluster Overview, the broker is running just fine. Anyone knows what the problem is? It doesn't seem like my transformation module is the problem, since the *movielens*-stream from the [documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/graph-stream-processing-with-kafka) connects with the same transformation module without problems (obviously there is an error thrown as soon as the transformation starts, but the stream can be connected and runs). But for the sake of completeness, here is my transformation module:

```py
    import mgp 
    import json
    
    @mgp.transformation
    def transfer(messages: mgp.Messages) -> mgp.Record(query=str, parameters=mgp.Nullable[mgp.Map]):
      result_queries = []
    
      for i in range(messages.total_messages()):
        message = messages.message_at(i)
        transfer_dict = json.loads(message.payload().decode('utf8'))
        result_queries.append(
          mgp.Record(
            query=(
              """
            MERGE (fromAccount:Account {accountId: $fromId, createTime: $fCreateTime, isBlocked: $fIsBlocked, accountType: $fAccountType, nickname: $fNickname, phonenum: $fPhonenum, 
            email: $fEmail, freqLoginType: $fFreqLoginType, lastLoginTime: $fLastLoginTime, accountLevel: $fAccountLevel})
            MERGE (toAccount:Account {accountId: $toId, createTime: $tCreateTime, isBlocked: $tIsBlocked, accountType: $tAccountType, nickname: $tNickname, phonenum: $tPhonenum, 
            email: $tEmail, freqLoginType: $tFreqLoginType, lastLoginTime: $tLastLoginTime, accountLevel: $tAccountLevel})
            MERGE (fromAccount)-[:TRANSFER {amount: $amount, createTime: $eCreateTime, orderNum: $orderNum, comment: $comment, payType: $payType, goodsType: $goodsType, 
            insertTime: $insertTime, exportTime: timestamp()}]->(toAccount)
            """),
            parameters={
              "fromId": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["fromId"], "fCreateTime": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["createTime"], "fIsBlocked": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["isBlocked"],
              "fAccountType": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["accountType"], "fNickname": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["nickname"], "fPhonenum": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["phonenum"], 
              "fEmail": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["email"], "fFreqLoginType": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["freqLoginType"], "fLastLoginTime": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["lastLoginTime"], 
              "fAccountLevel": transfer_dict["fromAccount"]["accountLevel"],
              "toId": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["toId"], "tCreateTime": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["createTime"], "tIsBlocked": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["isBlocked"],
              "tAccountType": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["accountType"], "tNickname": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["nickname"], "tPhonenum": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["phonenum"],
              "tEmail": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["email"], "tFreqLoginType": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["freqLoginType"], "tLastLoginTime": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["lastLoginTime"],
              "tAccountLevel": transfer_dict["toAccount"]["accountLevel"],
              "amount": transfer_dict["amount"], "eCreateTime": transfer_dict["createTime"], "orderNum": transfer_dict["orderNum"], "comment": transfer_dict["comment"], 
              "payType": transfer_dict["payType"], "goodsType": transfer_dict["goodsType"], "insertTime": transfer_dict["insertTime"]
            }
          )
        )
        return result_queries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out, that the *Broker Transport Failure* was thrown, because the docker container could not reach the port 9092 at localhost. The point is, that the docker-compose.yml file creates an own network, where each container can be reached through its name, as described in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). In the [docker-compose.yml from the memgraph docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#create-a-yaml-file) , the following line

```yaml
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

defines, that the broker is listening at address *broker:29092* in the compose network, and at *localhost:9092* on the host machine. So the correct server address to configure the stream from the memgraph UI would be

**broker:29092**

If you are using docker (not docker-compose!), then the following command works, to access kafka through *localhost:9092* within the memgraph docker, if a local kafka cluster is running.

```bash
docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 --network="host" --name memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform
```

Note, that now the docker container and the docker host will share the same network, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach). So if Kafka runs locally the docker container can access port 9092 on localhost

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is to connect the Source (Broker) to a Sink (Consumer).

In the linked docker-compose from the [docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#configure-memgraph), the guide uses the [Neo4j Kafka connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j).

Notice these lines in docker-compose:

```
command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
    confluent-hub install --no-prompt neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j:latest
    /etc/confluent/docker/run
```

So, if you have set the stream to use the [Source as the Neo4j Connector](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#configure-memgraph).

You should also set the [Sink as the Neo4j Connector](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#configure-the-sink-instance), based on JSON schema.

You probably set the **Neo4j connector Source (Broker)** and now try to connect via the **Python Transformation module (Consumer)**. Technically, that should be possible, but I guess we never tested this combination, and Neo4j Source is probably doing some pre-processing there, which is not compatible with our Python Query modules; they work with pure Kafka Brokers.

That is the reason why Kafka native stream (movie_lens) works with Python QM but not with Neo4j Kafka Connector.

My advice would be if you use Neo4j kafka Connector use it for both Source and Sink, or use native Kafka + Python QM.

We will probably explain this in the docs also, so it avoids further confusion. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, it works when I use the Neo4j Sink Connector for import. But, I am not using the Neo4j Source Connector to create the Kafka Stream. I am using native KafkaProducer to stream the JSON from a Java Application into the topic.